# Bookshelfjs : belongsTo() relationship

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I'm using ExpressJS and MySQL.

I'm trying to get a list of friends of a user, but I can't get the friend_id's information here. How can I include it to my query? It seems that it follows its own convention so it doesn't include friend_id to the query.

Here's what I get now :

```
[
    {"id":1,"user_id":1,"friend_id":2,"friends":
    {"id":1,"email":"user1@gmail.com","username":"user1"}},
    {"id":2,"user_id":1,"friend_id":3,"friends":
    {"id":1,"email":"user1@gmail.com","username":"user1"}}
]
```

I should be able to see friend_id = 2 and friend_id = 3's values too (id, email, username, etc)

friends table

```
id
user_id (foreign key from users table)
friend_id (foreign key from users table)
```

users table

```
id
name
email
```

Models

```
var friend = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'friends',
    friends: function () {
        return this.belongsTo(user);
    }
});

var user = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users'
});
```

Query

```
var friend = require('../models').friend;
var user = require('../models').user;


router.get('/relative', function (req, res) {
    friend.where('user_id', 1).fetchAll({withRelated: ['friends']}).then(function (friends) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(friends));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should update your query like below;

```
       friend.where('user_id', 1)
       .fetchAll({ 
          withRelated: [{
             'friend_id': function(qb) {
                qb.column('id','name')
           }}])
       .then(function (friends) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(friends));
        });
```

If this not solve your problem, you can try update your model like below;

```
var friend = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'friends',
    friends: function () {
        return this.belongsTo(user, 'friend_id');
    }
});
```